# Problem running GWTComplier in an ant script

Tags: java, gwt, ant

In eclipse when I compiled my GWT-modules then I got successful
compilation but when I tried to run my ant script for gwt compilation
I got the following error messages :

[ERROR] Errors in 'file:  ../../../... .java'
    [java]          [ERROR] Line 19: The import com.ensarm.......
cannot be resolved

Finding entry point classes
    [java]       [ERROR] Unable to find type .....*
    [java]          [ERROR] Hint: Previous compiler errors may have
made this type unavailable
    [java]          [ERROR] Hint: Check the inheritance chain from
your module; it may not be inheriting a required module or a module
may not be adding its source path entries properly..

Any idea/suggestion guys ?

Thanks,
Sachin.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the error it seems that you are missing some jar containing containing the missing classes. You need need to add that jar to the class path. Eclipse can find it but for the ant target the 'compile path' provided should include that jar.
Can you make sure it is there in your compile path.